Don't show the contents of a post that was deleted as "rude/abusive" in New Answers to Old Questions
When scrolling through /tools/new-answers-old-questions, it can be rather unpleasant and typically not useful to see the contents of posts that have already been deleted as rude/abusive inline. If it's not deleted, then it's unpleasant, but it's useful because it draws my attention to something that is actionable by me. But if it's already deleted, then there's basically nothing I care to do with it.
When viewing posts in Q&A pages, the contents of posts deleted as rude/abusive are hidden by default and require navigating to the post's revision history to see the contents. I'd like there to be a similar behaviour for the New Answers to Old Questions page.
